# What "subbus", "secbus" and "pribus" mean in output of sysctl in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, pci, sysctl

what is the meaning of these terms: "subbus", "secbus" and "pribus"
Here an example of the output:

dev.pcib.3.subbus: 2 
dev.pcib.3.secbus: 2 
dev.pcib.3.pribus: 0 
dev.pcib.3.domain: 0

Does it map to pci address (pci:U:X:Y:Z)?
Why it is not documented in sysctl man page? Where can I find more info about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "-d" option for sysctl. It provides short description for each system control like

```
dev.pcib.3.subbus=Subordinate bus number 
dev.pcib.3.secbus=Secondary bus number 
dev.pcib.3.pribus=Primary bus number 
dev.pcib.3.domain=Domain number
```

In particular case this is statistics information about buses attached to PCI bridge (aka pcib). So it's doesn't map to PCI ID.

Sysctl is just routine which gathering tunable / read-only variables over kernel modules. As result, it doesn't know meaning of each variable. Developer of particular functionality may describe meaning of sysctl variables, but I think it's rare case.

If you're looking for PCI information, it's worth to use "**pciconf -l -v**" and "**devinfo**".